Minecraft 1.20 modding - [Render thread/ERROR] [minecraft/RecipeManager]: Parsing error loading recipe: No key id in MapLike[{}]
I am making a Minecraft Forge mod with custom recipes, one of which is the following
{
  "type": "minecraft:crafting_shaped",
  "pattern": [
    "E",
    "S",
    "S"
  ],
  "key": {
    "E": {
      "item": "minecraft:emerald"
    },
    "S": {
      "item": "minecraft:stick"
    }
  },
  "result": {
    "item": "itemsplus:emerald_stick",
    "count": 1
  }
}

It however does not load into the game. The log shows the following error
[Render thread/ERROR] [minecraft/RecipeManager]: Parsing error loading recipe itemsplus:emerald_stick_from_crafting_table com.google.gson.JsonParseException: No key id in MapLike[{"item":"itemsplus:emerald_stick","count":1}]
How could I solve this?
I tried adding an "id" field in "result", but as expected it resulted in another error. The modid is well defined, and the item id is too.

Does this answer your question? Parsing error thrown when loading recipe (fabric)

I don't think its will be the same(I use fabric), but in "result", if you change "item" to "id" it should work.

In the end I just used custom datagen and the problem vanished, but thank you for your answer
